# How do I initialise a Python file_object without opening a file

Tags: python

I need to declare a file_object globally and much later, open a file and in so doing store a value to it.

To explain:
Python allows me to declare a string variable outside of any class or function by simply declaring:

```
stringName = str()
```

and then much later  assigning a value EG:

```
stringName = 'this is a string'
```

I need to do much the same with a file_object to which I can much later  assign a value EG:

```
fileObject = ????????
```

and later

```
fileObject = open('fileName', mode, bufsize)
```

How do I get this past Python's syntax filters?

Comment: your "declaring a string variable" is giving it a value, it's not a declaration it's a definition equivalent to `stringName = ''`

Answer (score 2):

You can define the variable as `None` and then use it in your local function via `global`:

```
file = None

def func():
    global file
    file = open(fname, 'w+')
```